# Does anyone know of any sprite collections?

Tags: java, 2d, sprite

I am making a 2D Java game.  I want the game to look nice, so I need good sprites, but I want to focus on the coding of the game, not the graphics design.  This project has a time constraint so having premade sprites would be very helpful.  Does anyone know of any good sprite collections?

Comment: Sprites... Haven't heard this word for 15 years...

Comment: Really?  I'm in my masters program and they are still teaching 2D Java games... Though they are talking about moving to C# around the time .NET 6.0 comes out :)

Comment: This isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow, but probably is on-topic for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @Kylotan You're right, though the fact that I was able to semi-randomly discover this free sprite collection by surfing SE (which I almost always surf) instead of gamedev (which I'd never surf) makes me happy no one zealously decided to close it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Open Game Art](http://opengameart.org/).

Quoted:

> OpenGameArt.org is a community that
>   brings like-minded coders and artists
>   together for the purpose of creating
>   Open Source video games, by providing
>   a human-edited, searchable database of
>   freely-licensed art resources.

Comment: That site is awesome!  Should save me a lot of time, Thanks a bunch for the link!